# How to show custom data (images) in dropdown box with button (emulating Combobox effect) using jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget and formatting the output to include an image along with its name in the dropdown using the "custom data and display" example. It works great. I'm attempting to emulate the Combobox effect as far as having a triangle button at the right which drops down all the options - including the image(s). Using this Combobox emulation with a button works as far as dropping down the 'value' of each item... but how do I make this button drop down the custom data [the formatted output in the ".data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )..."]?

Here is my code:

```
    $(function() {

    function log( message ) {
    $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
    $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "order-prints.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function( xmlResponse ) {
            var mydata = $( "print", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                return {
                    value: $( "name", this ).text(),
                    id: $( "id", this ).text(),
                    name: $( "name", this ).text(),
                    icon: $( "icon", this ).text()
                };
            }).get();

        var $myinput = $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
            source: mydata,
            minLength: 0,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "SELECTED: " + ui.item.name + ", ID: " + ui.item.id + ", ICON: " + ui.item.icon :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
                $( ".project-icon" ).attr( "src", "folder/slideshow2/thumbs/" + ui.item.icon );
                $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.id );
            }

        })

//-- begin button to drop down all options  
        .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

$("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")                     
.attr("tabIndex", -1)                     
.attr("title", "Show All Items")                     
.insertAfter($myinput)                     
.button({                         
    icons: {                             
        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"                         
    },                         
    text: false                     
})                     
.removeClass("ui-corner-all")                     
.addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")                   
.click(function() {                         
   if ($myinput.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
    $myinput.autocomplete( "close" );
         return;                         
    }                                              
    $(this).blur();                                                 
    $myinput.autocomplete("search", "");                         
    $myinput.autocomplete.focus();                     
})
//-- end button to drop down all options

            .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var imgsrc = "folder/slideshow2/thumbs/";
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a><div class='project-container'>" + item.name + ", " + item.id + "<img class='project-icon' src='" + imgsrc + item.icon + "'>" + "</div></a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };

        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have this working properly by adding "$($myinput)" to the _renderItem as follows:

```
$($myinput).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var imgsrc = "folder/slideshow2/thumbs/";
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a><div class='project-container'>" + item.name + ", " + item.id + "<img class='project-icon' src='" + imgsrc + item.icon + "'>" + "</div></a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```